# Capture Group Not Captured in Preg_replace Replacement

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, capture-group

I have the following code:

```
$f = 'IMG_1474.PNG';
preg_replace('/(.*)([.][^.]+$)/', '$1' . time() . '$2', $f)
```

which should split the `IMG_1474` and `.PNG` and add the epoch in between. The first capture group appears to be empty though.

If `preg_match` is used I can see the first capture group is not empty (so regex performs the same in PHP as on regex101).

```
preg_match('/(.*)([.][^.]+$)/', $f, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Functional demo: https://3v4l.org/VgDWJ (the `604147502` is the `time()` result)

My presumption is that something is happening with the concatenation on the replace bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the issue is the concatenation of the capture groups with `time()`.  Use this version instead:

```php
$f = 'IMG_1474.PNG';
$output = preg_replace('/(.*)([.][^.]+$)/', '${1}' . time() . '${2}', $f);
echo $output;
```

This prints:

```
IMG_14741604148316.PNG
        ^^^^^^^^^^  second since epoch (1970-01-01)
```

To understand why this is happening, we have to consider that variable substitution occurs before the `preg_replace` function call does.  So your concatenated replacement term:

```
'$1' . time() . '$2'
```

actually first becomes:

```
'$1' . '1604148623' . '$2'
```

which is:

```
'$11604148623' . '$2'
```

The "first" capture group here is probably being interpreted as `$11` (or `$116`, etc.), and is not defined.  This is why you are currently only getting the second capture group, but the first one is empty.  The solution I suggested uses `${1}` which preserves the capture group reference so it is available during the `preg_replace` call as you intend.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was incorrect in my statement `the 604147502 is the time() result` statement as well. The first integer of that was paired with my attempted capture group and lost because `$11` doesn't exist. Thanks.

Comment: @user3783243 ... and `$2` as you have it actually works, because nothing follows it.